# How do I replace a specific letter in a word but keep the letter if the word ends with it?

Tags: notepad++

In the Holy Word of God Almighty Jesus Christ, according to the original 1611 King James Holy Bible, words that began or contained an "s" were represented by an "ſ", but if the word ended with an "s" they used an "s".

For example: Moſes = Moses

In Notepad++ I want to replace every "s" in a word, whether it starts or contains an "s", with "ſ" except for the ending "s".

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace function`

If you have 1 word per line, use :

```
replace : (s)(?!$)
```

Else, use my neighbor's answer

```
replace : `s\B`
```

replace by : `f`

In my example :

```
test => teft
tests => tefts
```

Comment: The question asked about words, nothing about one word per line. Please try your regex on a line like `tests of tests`. Also, why have you put the `s` in a group?

Comment: I edited because I thought he had one word per line. I will propose both solution then ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone.